# parse.com get number of devices that received the push notification in PHP

Tags: php, parse-platform, push

I am sending push notifications with the parse.com PHP API.

I want to get the number of devices that received the notification. How can I get this number?

This is my code:

```
ParsePush::send(array(
    "where" => $queryAndroid,
    "data" => array(
        "title" => "the title",
        "alert" => "The alert",
        "badge" => "Increment"
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I did not get any answer here so my solution was to get the data from the application.

When a user opens the notification I call a web service to my server and add counter to my database.

That is not good enough because if a user dismisses the notification I don't know he received it.

If any one can add something it will be grate.

Thank you.